# C++ Como chamar um outro arquivo cpp no script

Tags: c++

Eu tenho dois arquivos cpp.
Um é o principal, o outro é um secundario que vai abrir programas do windows.
Então eu inclui os dois na mesma pasta.

No arquivo principal, eu adicionei: `#include iapt2.cpp` que é a segunda parte do script, porem ele diz que não tem arquivo no diretorio.

Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Dê mais detalhes de como está o projeto, o código. Incluir um `.cpp` dentro do outro quase sempre é um erro.

Comment: Votei para fechar como erro de digitação, mas também porque a pergunta não está clara e ainda porque pela sugestão de edição e comentários na resposta que falam sobre coisas que não estão na pergunta, só quem conhecia o problema podia responder a pergunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente:

```
#include "nomedocpp.h"
```

OBS: utilize aspas

Comment: Deu certo.Acho que agora tenho que declarar a função, para dar prosseguimento correto?

Comment: Sim, agora você pode acessar os recursos que criar nesse arquivo cpp.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. :D

Comment: De nada. Quando seu problema for selecionado marque na reposta. Qualquer dúvida faça o Tour para entender melhor.